# BigDecimal não permitir 3 casas após virgula

Tags: java

Pessoal estou fazendo uma divisão entre 2 BigDecimal e preciso que o sistema não permita 3 casas após a vírgula. Tenho um valor cheio e preciso dividir pela quantidade informada pelo usuário. se der até suas casas após a vírgula quer dizer que deu certo, se der 3 casas significa que o usuário preencher o valor errado, tem como fazer essa validação na hora de dividir usando BigDecimal?

Comment: Já tentou usar o setScale?

Comment: mas o setScale, caso de 3 casas ele não vai arredondar para duas?

Comment: Sim, não tinha entendido direito sua pergunta, agora que li novamente entendi mais ou menos o que tu quer.

Comment: Veja se isso pode ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899429/how-do-i-validate-precision-and-scale-with-bigdecimal

Comment: obrigado era isso mesm que gostaria "..scale()"

Comment: Por nada, se conseguiu resolver poste a solução, dessa forma você ajuda outras pessoas com o mesmo problema. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforma ajuda do techies para pegar a quantidade de casa após a virgula usar bigDecimal.scale()